# Htmlunit can't type in passwordfield

Tags: javascript, java, html, htmlunit

I'm trying to log in to a site with htmlunit, but whenever I try to type in the password field, it just becomes blank.

It works perfectly fine with the username field, but no matter what I try I can't get the password field to work. Does anyone know what the problem could be here? I'm able to type in both fields no problem, if I disable Javascript.

Target site = https://www.paragonclient.com/login?bnc=1&rsn=noOb&fromProt=&lng=

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)){

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.paragonclient.com/login?bnc=1&rsn=noOb&fromProt=&lng=");

        //final HtmlTextInput usernameInput = page.getHtmlElementById("Sentry_email");
        final HtmlInput passwordInput = page.getHtmlElementById("Sentry_password");
        final DomElement loginButton = page.getElementById("Sentry_button");

        System.out.println(page.asText());

        passwordInput.type("test2");

        System.out.println(page.asText());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output (Notice how the password placeholder doesn't get replaced with what I typed)

1st print

Member Login

E-mail Address

Password

Log In

.

2nd print

Member Login

E-mail Address

Log In

Comment: So probably they're doing something with JS.

Comment: There is a ton of JS behind the login page on that site.